# Custom ActiveAdmin filter for model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I need to create a filter for ActiveAdmin. The challenge is that I'm trying to filter through a model's method, instead of a model's field or column. Here is my code:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord

def complicated_method
  if something
   do this
  else
   do that
  end
end
```

And in my admin file I need:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  filter: :complicated_method, as: :numeric

end
```

Any tips? Thanks